# how to remove street address country city from billing information in magento

Tags: billing-address

how to remove street address country city from billing information in checkout page.i want to remove these above compulsory  fields at the time of checkout page.as i tried it in abstract page but it not

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the `required-class` from each of this field. You can use jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#billing\\:street1').removeClass('required-entry');
    jQuery('#billing\\:city').removeClass('required-entry');
    jQuery('#billing\\:country_id').removeClass('required-entry');
    jQuery('#billing\\:country_id').removeClass('validate-select');
}
```

in the `billing.phtml` from `checkout/onepage/`

Comment: Hi Pradeep how can we do this for specific country for example if country selected is India then CITY should not be required validation.