# Remove street address field and required attribute from shipping address

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout, shipping-address

I have a very custom use for Magento and I'm trying to remove street address from the checkout.  Currently I have:

```
class LayoutProcessor {
 /**
 * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
 * @param array $jsLayout
 * @return array
 */
 public function afterProcess(
     \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
     array  $jsLayout
 ) {
    $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['street'] = [
    'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/components/group',
    'required' => false,
    'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.street',
    'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
    'sortOrder' => 1005,
    'type' => 'group'
    ];

     return $jsLayout;
 }
}
```

Unfortunately, while this seems to have removed the street address and stopped it from being required when entering shipping address, once I continue to the Review & Payment page and press "Place Order" it provides the following error, stopping me from proceeding:

> Please check the shipping address information. street is a required field.

How can I stop this check and allow it to proceed?

[This solution](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/50157/how-to-remove-street-address-country-city-from-billing-information-in-magento) suggests that I can remove the required aspect of fields with jquery, but where would I put this js file and get magento to load it on the Review and Payment page?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I'm I think there is no simple solution because the database will need a street. What you could do it create a plugin on GuestShippingInformationManagement (you will also need to do this for the non guest version). And add a fake 'street'. Or make the field hidden and add a default string in the street field?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for removing street address field

This solution is for removing City field. You can use it for removing Street address field as will.

[Magento 2 : Remove the city field in checkout billing address](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/317952/magento-2-remove-the-city-field-in-checkout-billing-address/317954#317954)

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the file named di.xml in the path and add below code
   **app/code/MyCompany/MyModule/etc/di.xml**

   ```
   <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
            <plugin name="mycompany_mymodule_remove_street_address" type="MyCompany\MyModule\Plugin\RemoveStreetAddressField" />
        </type>
   ```
2. Create the Onepage.php file in the path
   **app/code/MyCompany/MyModule/Plugin/RemoveStreetAddressField.php**

   ```
   <?php

   namespace MyCompany\MyModule\Plugin;

    use Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessorInterface;

    class RemoveStreetAddressField
   {
       public function afterProcess(
       LayoutProcessorInterface $subject,
       array $result
   ) {
       if (isset($result['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
           ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['street'])) {

           // Remove street address field
           unset($result['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
               ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['street']);

           // Remove required attribute from street address field
           $result['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
               ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['street']['validation']['required-entry'] = false;
       }

       return $result;
     }
   }
   ```

3.Run the below commands and check.
**php bin/magento s:d:c**